# Tikz libraries for doing shadows and light

Tags: tikz-pgf

Do you think is possible to do something like this with `tikz`? Since I do not ever know from what begin with, can you tell me if there exist some libraries for doing the shadows, the light in the spheres and the arrows?

[image]

Comment: @alfC so probably in this case is easier, faster and with better results using some software like `Photoshop` or `Illustrator` (it seems vectorial) or the free analogues

Comment: I don't think Photoshop or Illustrator can help in doing properly projected shadows. Most likely you are going to end up with a http://www.PSdisasters.com/ . For "popular" point and click software take a look at Google SketchUp. @PaulGessler, I take that as an encouragement to convert the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of TeX or TeX friend (TikZ, Asymptote, Sketch, epiX) actually do shadows. The closest thing I saw is to project the shadow "manually" (needs coding, a lot probably): http://www.piprime.fr/751/asymptote-using-three_asy-fig0110/.

The safest bet would be to go POVray all the way. If the goal is to just show those "spins" you could get away with Asymptote + 3D (sphere + 3d arrow) + 2D version of it in the plane (circle + 2d arrow).